# What is this BMX brand logo?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

I bought the a new bike at the local BMX shop but what brand is this logo? I don't have any idea.

---

[image: whole bike]

Comment: Obvious question -- did you ask the shop?

Comment: The logo might be based around the Greek letter psi (Ψ). Unfortunately, if you try to Google for something like "bmx psi logo", you get fifteen billion hits about how many pounds per square inch you need to inflate your tyres to...

Comment: Can you post more images, of the entire frame?  Maybe something else can be matched.  FWIW, that looks like it might be a trident.

Comment: You bought a new bike from a shop and noone knows what brand it was?  Go back to the shop and ask for more information !!   Read your warranty paperwork !

Comment: I've seen this before, I'm going to ask some friends. Maybe you could look at the bottom of the bottom bracket, sometimes the brand or model is printed there alongside the serial number.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ı asked brand to shop they said total hangover h3 this is the problem its not total and i haber got warranty paperwork because of its custom bike it has this frame , blank hubs,blank tires, total bar etc.

Comment: So you bought this bike and now suspect it's not what the shop said it was?

Comment: They said it was total custom bmx.

Comment: @Criggie can you remember, was that second photo of the same bike, or of a known bike for comparison? I'm not seeing that white headtube logo from second photo in the first. New answer is citing the seat clamp as evidence which it might be, but I'm not sure it is 2 photos of the same bike. Doesn't exclude unknown bike from having same features

Comment: @Swifty OP posted the blue bike picture as an answer, which I moved into the question.   So I make no claims.  However you have an excellent eye - The bike photo has a white cross on the head tube, the top photo has the trident thing which is not white.  What's going on here ?       The two shades of Blue are similar but not the same (could be the lighting)    And the album cover shows the trident right in the middle.    Guessing they're two different bikes but identical perhaps?  Berkanb can you please clarify the photos ?

Answer (score 13):

I accidentally found the answer to this question by... listening to Judas Priest. Yep.

Here's a picture of Judas Priest "Painkiller" album cover:

[image]

You can see the exact same "double fork" imagery, which reminded me of this question I read months ago (it's actually a common logo they use, not just on that album cover).

It turns out a company named *Amity* did produce Judas Priest BMX frames. Here's that frame courtesy of VitalBMX:

https://www.vitalbmx.com/product/guide/Frames,7/Amity/Judas-Priest,4046

We can see part of the logo on the second picture (I haven't found a picture of that frame from the front):

[image]

This is further confirmed by that integrated seat post clamp hole, that we see on the question's full view of the bike. It's not that common of a setup, so this + the partial view of the logo above means it's pretty much certain that...

### The frame is an *Amity Judas Priest Frame*

Comment: Judging from OP's account activity, I doubt they will see this answer. But I'm still posting it because I can't believe I remembered that question while listening to Metal.

Comment: The fact that this  integrated seat post clamp hole is pretty rare is what allowed the store to market it as a Total Hangover frame, because that frame is one of the very few that does have the same setup. A customer finding out that's it's actually an Amity frame is pretty unlikely (I had never heard of that brand before)

Comment: Ha! That's fantastic! 

Answer (score 3):

The second bike in the original post is a ["Hangover" by "Total BMX" this model is the H2](https://www.bmxv2.com/fr/soldes/957-cadre-hangover-h2-20-6-black-total-bmx.html)

[image]
The head tube on the bike does not have the stamped logo in the first image.
[image]
There have been several [versions of the Hangover](https://totalbmx.com/blogs/news/hangover-h4-frame) - currently on H4. The headtube always has a sticker.

I'm still looking for the stamped logo
**EDIT**:
As Fatalize said it is an Amity Bike Co Judas Priest frame.
[Amity Bike Co went out of business in 2013](https://rideukbmx.com/brands/amity). Using the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/) to access their old site none of the pictures will load but [there is a text description](http://web.archive.org/web/20130417121410/http://www.amitybikeco.com/jpframe/jpframe.php):

> full cnc head tube with judas priest cnc logo

Here is the bike in the wild. It's listed as a [2014 Amity Priest Custom BMX](https://www.pinkbike.com/buysell/1923024/).
[image]

The cnc logo must have been peculiar to the 2013 model because the [2012 model has a different logo](https://www.vitalbmx.com/product/guide/Bikes,6/Amity/3Kingdoms,3020).
[image]

The logo is known as the "Judas Priest cross". It first appeared on the cover of the "Sad Wings of Destiny" album in 1976. Later the symbol replaced the letter "T" in their logo on the cover of the "Angel of Retribution" album in 2005.

Comment: Yes - OP never came back to clarify why the second photo was not the same bike as the first photo.  Shame really, there was a lot of effort here by many different users to answer the question.